# List users that are part of maximum concurrency session

Tags: sql-server, session, concurrency, window-functions

I have a database table with data as shown below.  I am trying to list the users that are members of the maximum number of concurrent users condition.
I was able to get the maximum concurrency by using the solution provided by Itzik Ben_Gan a simple lookup on Google for "Calculating Concurrent Sessions, Part 3" will get you there.  For this data set the answer is 3 (session rows ending 174,175,176)
I have researched the web but so far only found ways to simply count the number of concurrent sessions.  I want to extend that a bit further and get the actual users that were concurrent.

I have also attempted something along these lines.

SELECT L.VISIT_ID, L.PARTY_ID, L.FROM_DATE,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VISIT2 L2
  WHERE L2.PARTY_ID != L.PARTY_ID AND L2.FROM_DATE <= L.FROM_DATE ) AS COMEINS,

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VISIT2 L2
  WHERE L2.PARTY_ID = L.PARTY_ID AND L2.THRU_DATE <= L.THRU_DATE ) AS COMEOUTS

FROM VISIT2 L

My expected result is

- PARTY_ID
- 1000008021
- 1000006018
- 1000000002

Below is the table as well as the query to create the table.

Thank you everyone for any time you can spend on suggestions.

```html
<style type="text/css">
  table.tableizer-table {
    font-size: 12px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
  .tableizer-table td {
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
  }
  .tableizer-table th {
    background-color: #104E8B;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
  <tr class="tableizer-firstrow">
    <th>VISIT_ID</th>
    <th>PARTY_ID</th>
    <th>FROM_DATE</th>
    <th>THRU_DATE</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019158</td>
    <td>1000009015</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 00:57:04.837</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 02:08:22.003</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019159</td>
    <td>1000006000</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 08:21:04.227</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 10:29:28.477</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019160</td>
    <td>1000008018</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 08:49:21.937</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 09:13:10.937</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019161</td>
    <td>1000006019</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 09:27:43.657</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 10:30:17.437</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019162</td>
    <td>1000007007</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 10:13:14.520</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 10:29:07.733</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019163</td>
    <td>1000008011</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 11:01:14.217</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 11:07:20.047</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019164</td>
    <td>1000007011</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 11:05:19.570</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 12:48:20.787</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019165</td>
    <td>1000008018</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 11:37:52.123</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 14:55:55.593</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019166</td>
    <td>NULL</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 11:40:33.583</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 11:40:33.583</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019167</td>
    <td>NULL</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 11:40:47.573</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 11:40:47.573</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019168</td>
    <td>NULL</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 11:40:54.653</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 11:40:54.653</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019169</td>
    <td>1000007030</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 12:15:24.957</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 14:09:14.417</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019170</td>
    <td>NULL</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 15:32:53.630</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 15:35:02.327</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019171</td>
    <td>1000008018</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 15:34:05.667</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 16:23:50.257</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019172</td>
    <td>1000000002</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 16:31:04.303</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 17:09:37.147</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019173</td>
    <td>1000006008</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 16:41:35.013</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 17:14:53.093</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019174</td>
    <td>1000008021</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 17:40:07.073</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 20:10:40.720</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019175</td>
    <td>1000006018</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 18:43:06.783</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 18:49:16.310</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019176</td>
    <td>1000000002</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 19:57:35.370</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 19:57:49.297</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019177</td>
    <td>1000008021</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 20:10:43.693</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 20:32:34.370</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019178</td>
    <td>1000006018</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 22:26:35.477</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 22:26:49.773</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019179</td>
    <td>1000000002</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 22:27:37.017</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 22:31:14.750</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019180</td>
    <td>1000009016</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 22:40:17.093</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 22:40:32.523</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019181</td>
    <td>1000008021</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 23:12:04.840</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 23:23:27.990</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1000019182</td>
    <td>1000000002</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 23:20:09.737</td>
    <td>2014-02-18 23:26:29.827</td>
  </tr>
</table>
​
```

```html
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[VISIT2](
 [VISIT_ID] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
 [USER_LOGIN_ID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
 [PARTY_ID] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
 [FROM_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
 [THRU_DATE] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I just took a guess at your data.  I went ahead and cross applied all the users that have over lapping times with another user.  This will tell you when so and so was there who else was there at the same time.  You could also group it by date first so you could know for a time range instead of user who was there at the same time.  I gave you a fiddle as well.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/20fa29/2

```
    SELECT * 
FROM VISIT2 src
CROSS APPLY(
  SELECT USER_LOGIN_ID +','
  FROM VISIT2 ins
  where src.party_id = ins.party_id
  and ins.from_date between src.from_date and src.thru_Date
  for xml path('')
  ) otherguests(ids)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Although this did not answer my question, it helped me realize that there are two occasions where the concurrency is three, therefore there are 2 sets of answers.  These are for visit_id rows 159,160,161,162.  Note that 159 logs in first, then 160 but this user logs out before visitor 161 and then 162 logs last.  Your query is only comparing the FROM_DATE of each row with the cross table, where it should also include the THRU_DATE.  Moreover you would need to use src.party_id != ins.party_id so that you don't compare yourself.  Anyone else care to help further? Thx

Comment: Actually after playing around with your suggestion I arrived at this.  Note I use DISTINCT to remove duplicates SELECT * 
FROM VISIT2 SRC
CROSS APPLY(
  SELECT USER_LOGIN_ID +','
  FROM VISIT2 INS
  WHERE SRC.PARTY_ID != INS.PARTY_ID
  AND INS.FROM_DATE BETWEEN SRC.FROM_DATE AND SRC.THRU_DATE
  AND INS.THRU_DATE < SRC.THRU_DATE
  FOR XML PATH('')
  ) OTHERGUESTS(IDS) \n  It doesn't give me the rows but it is close enough to give me the ids that I was looking for.

Comment: BTW the other concurrency takes place during visits 174,175,176.  I am just writing all this feedback so that others can benefit.  @JStead, if you please correct your response above I will mark it as answered, however perhaps others can post an answer where the responses are returned as individual rows.